# How to export hierarchy Kendo UI grid to excel including collapsed rows?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a 3-level hierarchy grid and need to export all the data including collapsed rows to excel. I am following this demo http://dojo.telerik.com/ApaqOJuv. But it only exports the expanded rows. How can I modify this solution so that it exports all the data?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to export all data, with `serverPaging` set to `true`, then the only way to export it through kendo is to expand all data, when expanding you are populating grid with new data (sending a request to the server), after that, you can export. Keep in mind you will only export the first page if you want all data you will need to show all in one page. Otherwise, you will need to handle exporting on the server-side.

Why? As you can see in the console of posted example, data is loaded when you expand the grid, so if it's collapsed there is no data, therefore, you can't export something that does not exist's. Kendo export is client-side exporting which means export only what you see.

Comment: Thanks, that's very clear. I tried to expand all the data using the grid method expandRows before exporting to excel, and when this is expanded automatically, it messes up the ordering. BTW, to export on the server-side, what approach I can take using C#  and .NET?